# Exporting Microsoft Office 16.0 Office Library and use it with Excel 2013

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I used Excel 2016 to create an Excel table with VBA program to generate a Word Document report automatically. The macro generates a compile error when used on Excel 2013 with older Office Library.

I tried the following without success:

- using an older version of Excel to save the macro (no improvement).
- changing the code (e.g: Word.Application -> Object) as proposed on other threads. The main problem is that the program is ~2000 lines long and when I fix something, another compile error arise a few lines later. Plus, the formatting in the Word document is altered.
- updating to Office 2016 is not a solution either for various compatibility reasons with other programs.

The only remaining solution I can see is to export the Microsoft Office 16.0 Office Library and the Microsoft Excel 16.0 Library to the computers running Excel 2013 and adding them to the VBA References.

I cannot locate these 2 Libraries. The path is shown in the Tools->References window but is cut because the window is too short (and of course not possible to resize).

What is the path and file name to the 2 libraries?

Do you think that this solution will work and if not, do you know a better one or a workaround?

Comment: You can use Application.Version to determine the version and load the references by code. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\Excel.Exe is the path for my 2010 Excel.

Comment: Open the workbook in the earliest (2013) version, remove the current reference to (v16) and add the (v15) object library and re-save (Office is backwardly compatible in this regard)

Comment: Thank you for your comments: 
to Nathan_Sav: I can locate the path of Excel but not the concrete library to export                                                                  .

to Alex K. : if it is what you suggested, on Excel 2013, when I remove the "Missing v16" reference and only keep the v15 reference, I still have compile error on certain functions like CleanString for example.

Comment: You really need to post the code your trying to use, along with the actual error message you're receiving. Alex K's suggestion is the approach to take here, I'm certain you cannot do what you are proposing.

Comment: I agree with @andshrew comment and confirm that you can't "export" the 2016 library to use with 2013. You MUST use the version of the library released with the version of Office. The big question will be whether you're trying to use functionality that's not even available in the older version...

Comment: as everyone else has said, there isn't a quick and easy fix to this.  You're going to have to pay the piper and update your code to use late binding with version checking.  Depending on how you've set up your variable, this can be relatively simple or pain stacking process...but unfortunately, in my experience it's the only way to sort out your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I guess I'll have to take the painful way after all